# Plotting seaborn heatmap on top of a background picture

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, seaborn

I am creating a heatmap through seaborn in Jupyter to display the amount of people that would choose a certain coordinate point.  I currently have the heatmap created with the following code

```
cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(yVals, xVals)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt="0.3f", linewidth=0.5, cbar=False,
              cmap="Reds", square=True, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

My questions are how could I plot this heatmap on top of a background image and to make the squares in the heatmap more transparent the closer to 0 they are to show the background image more?  Also is there a way to start the indexes on the heatmap at 1 instead of 0?

Here's a link to the picture as well if needed to see how it looks.

[image: Here's a link to the picture as well if needed to see how it looks.]

Comment: You would need to add an `imshow` plot with lower `zorder` to the axes and use a custom colormap for the heat, which has alpha less than 1 in it. In general, using matplotlib to create the heatmap instead of seaborn, may make it more transparent which options you have, see [this example](http://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html).

Answer (score 16):

You also need to scale/flip the images so they plot together, because the map is probably much finer resolution than the heatmap. We let Seaborn do its adjustment work and then match it in `imshow` which displays the map.

You can modify or create a colormap to have transparency near 0, and I left the code in to show you how, but the resulting figure was suboptimal because I couldn't read the map under high-heat locations. As shown, the whole heatmap is translucent.

Left for the reader: change the tickmarks to refer to map coordinates, not heatmap indices.

```
# add alpha (transparency) to a colormap
import matplotlib.cm from matplotlib.colors 
import LinearSegmentedColormap 
wd = matplotlib.cm.winter._segmentdata # only has r,g,b  
wd['alpha'] =  ((0.0, 0.0, 0.3), 
               (0.3, 0.3, 1.0),
               (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))

# modified colormap with changing alpha
al_winter = LinearSegmentedColormap('AlphaWinter', wd) 

# get the map image as an array so we can plot it 
import matplotlib.image as mpimg 
map_img = mpimg.imread('tunis.png') 

# making and plotting heatmap 
import numpy.random as random 
heatmap_data = random.rand(8,9) 

import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

hmax = sns.heatmap(heatmap_data,
            #cmap = al_winter, # this worked but I didn't like it
            cmap = matplotlib.cm.winter,
            alpha = 0.5, # whole heatmap is translucent
            annot = True,
            zorder = 2,
            )

# heatmap uses pcolormesh instead of imshow, so we can't pass through 
# extent as a kwarg, so we can't mmatch the heatmap to the map. Instead, 
# match the map to the heatmap:

hmax.imshow(map_img,
          aspect = hmax.get_aspect(),
          extent = hmax.get_xlim() + hmax.get_ylim(),
          zorder = 1) #put the map under the heatmap

from matplotlib.pyplot import show 
show()
```

[image: Translucent heatmap plotted over a scaled map]

Comment: Deserved an upvote.  Code could be improved to not produce `SyntaxError`.

Comment: i already have the heatmap on top of background map code. turns out what i was missing was the alpha parameter, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg 

file = "./iris.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file)
import seaborn as sns
map_img = mpimg.imread('1538287373.02485_image.png') 
 # Custom it with the same argument as 1D density plot
hmax = sns.kdeplot(df.sepal_width, df.sepal_length, cmap="Reds", shade=True, bw=.15)
hmax.collections[0].set_alpha(0)

plt.imshow(map_img, zorder=0, extent=[0.5, 8.0, 1.0, 7.0])
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]