# How to draw a Heatmap in a image using the coordinates in Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, heatmap

I've a huge list of Coordinates(x,y) of people walking in the streets and I like to design a heatmap using those Coordinates(x,y), i.e., it should look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYyAc.jpg). I want much **hotter spot** for multiple coordinates in a single spot, hotter means **red colored spot**. I've tried [this](https://zbigatron.com/generating-heatmaps-from-coordinates/) but ended up getting a heatmap like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68NFb.png) not the one I expected nor the site mentioned in the beginning(the wikipedia heatmap). This is the code I tried,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
x,y = [230,150,200],[200,100,150]
plt.imshow(img)
ax = sns.kdeplot(x,y, cmap = "Blues", shade= True, shade_lowest=False)
ax.set_frame_on(False)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('heatmap_pic.png')
```

This code also made the result image size smaller the actual image was much bigger. I'm new to OpenCV and Matplotlib someone please help me with this, to plot a Heatmap([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAIrG.jpg)) in a image using a bunch of Coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take image, create the heatmap, and superimpose it.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020894/how-to-superimpose-heatmap-on-a-base-image) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091591/plotting-seaborn-heatmap-on-top-of-a-background-picture).