# Seaborn heatmap over image but nothing is showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to put a heatmap over an image I have using seaborn and matplotlib, but the output doesn't show anything. I looked at the first answer of:

[Plotting seaborn heatmap on top of a background picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091591/plotting-seaborn-heatmap-on-top-of-a-background-picture)

I took nearly the exact same code and nothing is showing I don't know why.

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg 
import matplotlib.cm
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wd = matplotlib.cm.winter._segmentdata # only has r,g,b  
wd['alpha'] =  ((0.0, 0.0, 0.3), 
               (0.3, 0.3, 1.0),
               (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))

al_winter = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('AlphaWinter', wd) 

map_img = mpimg.imread('./my_picture.png') 

hmax = sns.heatmap(results,
            cmap = al_winter, # this worked but I didn't like it
            #cmap = matplotlib.cm.winter,
            alpha = 0.5, # whole heatmap is translucent
            annot = True,
            zorder = 2
            )

# The heatmap is working as I can see the output in my notebook.

hmax.imshow(map_img,
          aspect = hmax.get_aspect(),
          extent = hmax.get_xlim() + hmax.get_ylim(),
          zorder = 1) #put the map under the heatmap
plt.show()

# Here the output is empty.
```

The last output is empty and I don't know why, I tried to do `hmax.imshow(map_img)` and nothing is showing too except `<matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x129888670>`. Is this normal? I'm not sure if the problem comes from my picture, heatmap, or code.

Comment: I've experienced that sometimes `sns` refused to render on small figure sizes but ran fine on bigger figures.

Comment: So I should increase the size of my image? Or the size of my heatmap?

Comment: Size of the heatmap. put, e.g. `plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))` before `hmax = sns.heatmap(...)``

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added the line you mentioned and saw on my notebook that the heatmap is indeed bigger, but still no output for the last command `hmax.imshow(...)`...

Comment: Maybe `'./my_picture.png'` contains a bad image?  Did you test displaying only the image (as in `plt.imshow(map_img)`)?  What is `results.shape`?

Comment: Maybe it comes from the image. `plt.imshow(map_img)` outputs my image correctly though. And `results.shape` outputs (8,5)

Comment: UPDATE: I'm gonna try to save the heatmap as a png and then 'superimpose' the two files. Maybe that will work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I saved the heatmap as a png and then 'superimposed' the two pictures using Image (PIL package). Doing it this way didn't cause me any trouble.

I still don't know why it didn't know work with the code in the question. Feel free to post an answer if you have a solution.