# Plot a Seaborn heatmap over a background picture

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a following problem. I would like to plot my heatmap over an image. See my simplified code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 1], [4, 5, 1], [7, 8, 2], [8, 2, 3]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

#make the df heatmap friendly
df_cnt = df.reset_index().pivot(index='a', 
                                            columns='b', values='c')

#missing values 
df_cnt.fillna(0, inplace=True)

#load an image
my_image = Image.open("./image.png")

#plot a an image
plt.imshow(my_image, zorder = 0)
#Note: I can see the image correctly in my IDE

#plot a heatmap
h = sns.heatmap(df_cnt)

#Heatmap is displayed but it is not over the backroung image....
```

What is the problem here? Is it because the color for 0 values in my heatmap is black?

I tried to follow answer here, but it did not work to me: [Plotting seaborn heatmap on top of a background picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091591/plotting-seaborn-heatmap-on-top-of-a-background-picture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mpl.image in the answer you are referring to to overlay the image. You need to make sure to specify the transparency of the heatmap.

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg # add
h = sns.heatmap(df_cnt, alpha=0.1, zorder=2) # update
my_image = mpimg.imread("./image.png") # update
# update
h.imshow(my_image,
         aspect=h.get_aspect(),
         extent= h.get_xlim() + h.get_ylim(),
         zorder=1)

plt.show() # add
```